# Keyboard shortcut for R assignment operator (<-) in VSCode in editor and terminal

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

How would I add a keyboard shortcut for the basic [assignment operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) (`<-`) that works both in the editor **AND** the terminal?

Getting it to work in the editor is [straightforward](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) (content goes into `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+-",
  "command": "type",
  "when": "editorLangId == r && editorTextFocus || editorLangId == rmd && editorTextFocus",
  // if you want using quarto, try this
  // "when": "editorLangId =~ /r|rmd|qmd/ && editorTextFocus",
  "args": {"text": " <- "}
}
```

But I'm struggling with understanding what the `when` clause would need to look like for the terminal.

Things I tried based on the [official doc on when clauses](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts):

- using `terminalFocus`

```
{
    "key": "alt+-",
    "command": "type",
    // "when": "editorLangId == r && editorTextFocus || editorLangId == rmd && editorTextFocus || terminalFocus",
    "args": {"text": " <- "}
}
```

- additional explicit language ID based on [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)

```
{
    "key": "alt+-",
    "command": "type",
    // "when": "editorLangId == r && editorTextFocus || editorLangId == rmd && editorTextFocus || editorLangId == shellscript && terminalFocus",
    "args": {"text": " <- "}
}
```

Comment: How can I access `keybindings.json`?

Comment: @Rappster Hi. Is the a way to make the assignment "<-" to behave like on Emacs? That is: press  "ctrl+_" one time and you have "<-"; press two times and you get the underscore "_" it self. Appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `type` command to write to the terminal.  Try this instead:

```
{
  "key": "alt+-",  // or whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
      "text": " <- "
  },
  "when": "terminalFocus && !terminalTextSelected"
}
```

See [send text to terminal docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_custom-sequence-keybindings)